# how to handle end of a comboBox

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I have a comboBox in my winforms application that populates based on data from my SQL Express Database, it increments by one each time the user clicks the "next record" button. Which has this simple code that does the operation:

```
 comboBox4.SelectedIndex = comboBox4.SelectedIndex + 1;
```

How would I handle the exception when it has reached the end of the comboBox? Because when it reaches the end there is no value to go to next after the code above runs. How would I let's say have  a MessageBox pop up that says "you have reached the end of your comboBox?"

Comment: What have you tried? With an `if()` and a `comboBox4.Items.Count` you'll come quite far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check with `Items.Count` of ComboBox before incrementing the `SelectedIndex`.

```
if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex < comboBox1.Items.Count - 1)
    comboBox1.SelectedIndex += 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are fetching from SQL Express, you can identify the `COUNT` of these records. That will let you know the total number of such records. Let's say, you save it in a variable of type `int` named `Count`.

You can then write your code as :

```
int count  = //get the total number of such records from the database
if (comboBox4.SelectedIndex != (count -1))
{
    comboBox4.SelectedIndex = comboBox4.SelectedIndex + 1;
}
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: `comboBox4.SelectedIndex = comboBox4.SelectedIndex++` is not the same as `comboBox4.SelectedIndex = comboBox4.SelectedIndex + 1`. Removing code is not always a simplification. You also don't need to do another query to the database to do a count, you have assigned the items to the combobox, so you can just use `Items.Count`.

Comment: @CodeCaster I get your point. In this context, that's correct.

Comment: Yeah so remove the simplification paragraph, it adds nothing. You're also off by one, SelectedIndex is zero-based.

Comment: Why not use the count of the Combobox4.Items.Count and skip the query on the database. Seems much more efficient to me

Comment: SelectedIndex is 0 based and count is 1 based ! If you have one element you will have 0 != 1, which is true and you will have a nice OutofRangeException.